# Best way to score and sum in Scala?

Tags: scala, sum

Is there a better way of doing this:

```
val totalScore = set.foldLeft(0)( _ + score(_) )
```

or this:

```
val totalScore = set.toSeq.map(score(_)).sum
```

I think it's quite a common operation so was expecting something sleeker like:

```
val totalScore = set.sum( score(_) )
```

Comment: The first two pieces of code do different things. See my comment to Daniel C. Sobral's answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, there are alternative ways to write it:

```
val totalScore = set.toSeq.map(score(_)).sum
val totalScore = set.toSeq.map(score).sum
val totalScore = set.toSeq map score sum
```

The last one may require a semi-colon at the end if the next line doesn't start with a keyword. One can also use `.view` instead of `.toSeq`, which would avoid allocating a temporary collection. However, I'm not sure the `.view`'s present behavior (of showing repeated elements) is the correct one.

Comment: This seems like the simplest and most appropriate solution. I'd prefer to read this instead of having a function that includes doing the mapping.

Comment: A legitimate concern with the two step approach may be performance -- it creates a second list just to sum it. However, you can use a view to avoid this overhead: `set.view.map(score).sum`. Separating the concerns of mapping and summing avoids a blow-out of methods in the standard library. If you do it frequently, you can add `mapAndSum` to your own code.

Comment: Does anyone have a link to some documentation on views?

Comment: This code has a bug! Namely, if `set` is indeed of type `Set[_]` and `score` assigns the same value to two elements of `set` (i.e. `score(a) = score(b)` where `a`, `b` are in `set` and `a != b`), then they only get counted once. Hence, it's not only that the "lazy" `set.view.map.(score(_)).sum` is more performant, it is actually the only correct way to do it! (I actually just encountered this bug in my code.)

Comment: @dsg Great catch. Though one could always do a `toSeq` instead.

Answer (score 5):

`Seq.sum` does not take a function which could be used to score the sum. You could define an implicit conversion which "pimps" `Traversable`:

```
implicit def traversableWithSum[A](t: Traversable[A])(implicit m: Numeric[A]) = new {
  def sumWith(f: A => A) = t.foldLeft(m.zero)((a, b) => m.plus(a, f(b)))
}

def score(i: Int) = i + 1

val s = Set(1, 2, 3)

val totalScore = s.sumWith(score _)
println(totalScore)
=> 9
```

Please note that the `Numeric` trait only exists in Scala 2.8.

Comment: Michel, I like your solution and I'd thought I would make it a bit more generic by allowing score to work on an object, like "Game" and return a Numeric:

implicit def traversableWithSum[A](t: Traversable[A]) = new {
  def sumWith[B](f: A => B)(implicit m: Numeric[B]): B = t.foldLeft(m.zero)((a, b) => m.plus(a, f(b)))
}

Answer (score 1):

Simpler:

```
scala> val is1 = Set(1, 4, 9, 16)
is1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 4, 9, 16)
scala> is1.reduceLeft(_ + _)
res0: Int = 30
```

With your score method:

```
scoreSet.reduceLeft(_ + score(_))
```

Warning, though, this fails is the collection being reduced is empty while fold does not:

```
scala> val is0 = Set[Int]()
is0: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set()

scala> is0.foldLeft(0)(_ + _)
res1: Int = 0
```

Comment: This won't work. The type of the collection is different than the type of the result (which is the reason for the call to `score`), so `reduceLeft` is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, the `Seq#sum` overload that takes an implicit conversion to `Numeric` could be used if the type in the collection to be scored / summed does not itself have an addition operator. However, because it's an implicit conversion parameter, it won't be applied unless required to make the reduce closure type-check.